# What are the differences between "Our democracy is what is at stake." and "Our democracy is at stake."

Tags: difference

"Our democracy is what is at stake." and "Our democracy is at stake." Both have same meaning, but what are the differences.

Answer (score 1):

There is semantically very little difference. And pragmatically, both sound like a dramatic call to arms.

The longer version covertly refers to 'as opposed to other issues'. This might be as a counter to some other issues that someone has raised, either not realising how important the key issue was, thinking their issues were equally important, or in an attempt to derail.

Or it might be a further attempt to emphasise: "It is nothing less than our democracy that is at stake!"

Comment: Hi! I hope you are fine! I upvoted your good answer!

Answer (score 1):

"Our democracy is what is at stake." emphasizes the subject more than "Our democracy is at stake." but just as Edwin mentioned they are essentially the same.

I would use the first instance if there was other related content before the statement (such as if one was in an argument). The second phrase is fine by itself or with other related statements.